# Fixed Point Scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, numerical-optimization, fixed-point-iteration

I want a fixed point scheme that will converge for all values of ' $a$ ' . 
$$x = \sin(x) - ax + 30$$

I have tried a couple of options but none works for all values of '$a$'

Comment: Is $x$ in radians ?

Comment: Not provided, but i think its in degrees.

Comment: I have even tried   x =  sin(x) + 30 / (1+ a) 

But it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Why would you think that?  In any problem not specifically involving angles, the argument of the trig functions should be in radians.  In any case, that really is not important to this problem.

Comment: I was doing the other problem from same problem set where x was in degrees so i assumed here too is the case.

Comment: @user247327: how do you know ?

Comment: Note that as the sine is small compared to $30$, the solution is always very close to $30/(1+a)$.

Comment: What is your starting value ?

Answer (score 0):

$x=(\sin x + 30)/(1+a)$ (note the parentheses) is the natural try and will work well when $a \not \in [-2,0]$  When $a$ is in that interval the derivative can be greater than $1$ in absolute value.  In that case you want $x=\arcsin ((1+a)x-30)$ but I don't see a way to get one expression that works for all $a$.

Comment: Another proposed solution was   
 x =  ( sin(x) - xcos(x) +30 )/(1 + a - cos(x))

Comment: But it fails as well